# Google Maps Api using php

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to use the maps API provided by Google 
i had search a lot on Google and also on Bing But i found nothing there which help me to integrate the Google maps API
i had already apply

1. map marker
2. and lots of thing

you can see my work at 
"[http://23.231.48.155/~niteshku]"
by selecting the location you want

actually i am trying to integrates the same maps as it is in the below give URL

http://www.proptiger.com/v2/dist/maps/noida-real-estate

kindly help me its looks very interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try reading through the Google documentation first:

[Google Maps Developers](https://developers.google.com/maps/)

The maps are a client-side application based on Javascript (but doesn't mean you have to use JS), PHP is server side so you don't really need to depend on it. One reason you might want to integrate them is if you had some marker coordinates stored in a database for example.

```
The Google Maps Image APIs make it easy to embed a static Google Maps image 
or Street View panorama into your web page, with no need for JavaScript.
```

Here's a JSFiddle showing what you need for a basic implementation of the Maps API. Have a play around with it and work out what the code does etc. Note the customised colours are not really necessary but look nice

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/xrHar/)